# how to kill huge process by killing the daemon itself

Tags: linux, rhel, kill, ps, fuser

on our rhel machine we saw huge lines as  ( total lines numbers are 856 )

that cause very high cpu load average

```
root     110490 108840  0 07:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/get_params/daemon.py --state-docker-json worker-exp
root     110500 109213  0 07:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/get_params/daemon.py --state-docker-json worker-exp
root     110507 108848  0 07:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/get_params/daemon.py --state-docker-json worker-exp
root     110508 108570  0 07:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/get_params/daemon.py --state-docker-json worker-exp
root     110519 109331  0 07:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/get_params/daemon.py --state-docker-json worker-exp
root     110552 108776  0 07:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/get_params/daemon.py --state-docker-json worker-exp
root     110553 109214  0 07:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/get_params/daemon.py --state-docker-json worker-exp
.
.
.
.
```

so we can kill all the process by kill as

```
kill 110490
kill 110500
.
.
.
```

or maybe use with fuser command that can kill all pids that related to `/var/tmp/get_params/daemon.py` , it can be much more elegant instead to use so many kill commands

so how to use `fuser` or other approach that can kill the pids ,

Comment: Do you recall installing that program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pkill` can take care of this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/694589/86440), as can `fuser`:

```
fuser -k /var/tmp/get_params/daemon.py
```

Answer (score 4):

`pkill -f /var/tmp/get_params/daemon.py`